# Can TVöD table in Germany be used as comparison for salary negotiation?

Tags: software-industry, salary, germany

The TVöD table is used only for state jobs, as far as I understand. Can this table be used as reference for realistic salary expectations (as a Software Developer) or is it way too high or way too low compared to the actual average salaries?

Comment: In comparison to industry, the state pays absolutely lousy for developers. It's of course location dependant, but in the frankfurt metro area for instance private industry devs get 40-80% more depending on seniority and specialization

Comment: @Magisch Flesh that out a bit and that sounds like a good answer to me!

Comment: @Magisch But it’s correct to assume that the values in the table are the minimum salary for degree/years or experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are job postings for software developers in public service, and they are usually in the E10..E12 range. But I'd say it's a bit low compared to industry, and some of those postings even say that they are willing to pay a bit more ("Zulage").

You could also compare this to IG Metall, which is quite a bit higher for the same levels, and has [increased more in the last twenty years](https://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/vergleich/entwicklung1/). A software developer would be in the EG 11..13 level in IG Metall, AFAIK.